# How to keep the side bar link active when i change the tabs using angular2

Tags: css, angular

i have a side bar, where in it remains active if im on the screens first tab, if i switch to second tab, the url changes and the sidebar label wont be active.
How can this be solved. Please help.

HTML:

**Side bar Code:**

```
 <a routerLink="/my-health/my-health-history" [ngClass] = "{'active' : true}" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between"
        id="nav-link-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-submenu-1">
        <span><i class="icon-heart g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-8"></i>{{ 'DashboardModule.MYHEALTH' | translate }}
        </span>
      </a>
```

**TAbs code redirected to pages on click of side bar link:**

```
<div class="myhealth mt7">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs menu">
    <li>
      <a class="active-link" routerLink="/my-health/my-health-history" routerLinkActive="active-link"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">myHealthHistory
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/my-health/my-lifestyle" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">myLifeStyle
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/my-health/my-family-health-history" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">myFamilyHistory
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If i am in myHealth History tab, then side bar will be active, if i shift to other 2 tabs then side bar wont be active

Answer (score 0):

Using `[ngClass] = "{'active' : true}"` in  tag.

Comment: thanks for response, should i use this in tabs html?

Comment: Yes. If it is not resolved. Please show your problem in jsfiddle/stackblitz for better response rate.

Comment: i added that part of code in side bar component, it worked but it remains active all time

Comment: Based on some condition you can activate. Say for example [ngClass] = "{'active' : (title == 'some text') }"

Comment: based on router links can we make it active?

Comment: Yes u can do it

Comment: [ngClass] = "{'active' : (routerLink == '/my-health/my-lifestyle') }"

Comment: is this correct?can u edit my side bar html code for both the routes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184669/discussion-between-sankar-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 0):

The condition are:

1. Differ your current URL based on tab change.

   ex1: http://test.com/tab1 and http://test.com/tab2

   ex2:http://test.com/#tab1 and http://test.com/#tab2
2. Read url and find string like "tab1 or tab2"
3. add "Active" class based on this condition

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the current active link in the sidebar component.

#### Sidebar html

```
<a routerLinkActive="active-link" [ngClass]="{'active-link': isActive()}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between"
        id="nav-link-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-submenu-1">
        <span><i class="icon-heart g-pos-rel g-top-1 g-mr-8"></i>{{ 'DashboardModule.MYHEALTH' | translate }}
        </span>
      </a>
```

#### Sidebar ts

```
 constructor(private router:Router) {
  }

 isActive(){
     return ["/my-health/my-health-history","/my-health/my-lifestyle","/my-health/my-family-health-history"].includes(this.router.url);
 }
```

> Note : the code is written directly to Stackoverflow editor so there could be typo or syntatical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: Cannot read property 'isActive' of undefined, i am getting this

Comment: It means Sidebar and Tabs are two different component. Isn't it ?

Comment: ya, both are different

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: here when i click on sidebar, it is not navigating to the page

Comment: Please create stackblitz.com demo.

Comment: if i use routerLink="/my-health/my-health-history", then it navigates

Comment: here 3 2 components are der na so finding bit difficult to do demo.. il try still